# Python communication with java program does not echo inputs

Tags: java, python, subprocess

Python communicating with java program:

**Java Program**

```
Sample.java    
import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class
    
    class Sample {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x, y, sum;
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("Type a number:");
        x = myObj.nextInt(); // Read user input
        System.out.println("Type another number:");
        y = myObj.nextInt(); // Read user input
    
        sum = x + y;  // Calculate the sum of x + y
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum); // Print the sum
      }
    }
```

**Python Program:**

```
import subprocess;
p = subprocess.Popen(['timeout' ,'2', 'javac', 'Sample.java'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p = subprocess.Popen(['timeout' ,'1', 'java', 'Sample'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr = p.communicate(b"5\n6\n")
p.stdin.close()
print(stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

When I execute python program, I get the following result

```
Type a number:
Type another number:
Sum is: 11
```

The expected result is

```
Type a number:5
Type another number:6
Sum is: 11
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here, is basically the same as running a pipe from the shell. When you run, for example,

```
sort somefile | uniq
```

the sorted data, as read by uniq, does not get echoed! Or, even simpler,

```
./someprogram <file
```

does not echo the contents of file (unless `someprogram` explicitly sends it to stdout). So what's going on?

*Echo does not happen on reading from stdin, it happens in the terminal device driver.*

In your example, there is no terminal involved, so there is no echo. If you want the data you send to the subprocess to also show up on stdout, you have to explicitly write it to stdout.

Answer (score -1):

Below code should work as when you are trying to communicate from python you are sending the arguments , for them to be printed on the output you have to log them

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x, y, sum;
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("Type a number:");
        x = myObj.nextInt(); // Read user input
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println("Type another number:");
        y = myObj.nextInt(); // Read user input
        System.out.println(y);
    
        sum = x + y;  // Calculate the sum of x + y
        System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum); // Print the sum
      }
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: In your code, the process waits for input from the user. It should happen automatically by passing through proc.communicate.